Ancova or other test?
I am struggling to select the correct type of test for my data and would like to eventually run it in R. The design is as follows:
A treatment vs control group of plants
From each plant the following is taken:

6 young leaves
6 old leaves
A vigor index value

From the leaves protein is measured and averaged per plant for young and old (2 values per plant, age) and compared control vs treatment.
Therefore we have data which appears as follows:



Plant
Treatment
Age
Protein
Vigor




C1
C
o
2.238
0.264


C1
C
y
3.0932
0.264


T1
T
o
1.724
0.195


T1
T
y
1.214
0.195


C2
C
o
1.101
0.134


C2
C
y
2.422
0.134


....







At first I thought we could do a standard 2way anova but it seemed that with one of the values being paired (Age) while the treatment are performed on different plants at the same time, this should be independent, this may not work. We did some simple paired t-tests with the data comparing treated old vs treated young plant protein values and this returned a statistically significant result at p = 0.01, while the 2way anova returned no significance. There also appears to be a clear effect size in this comparison, so it seems the wrong test.
Then we tried both a repeat measured anova and ancova with vigor as the covariable, however because of my limited statistics background I'm nervous that 1) its the incorrect test and 2) my codes are incorrectly set up, as I am trying to use other examples to set this up and honestly, I have yet to find something with quite the same variable arrangement online.
Below is the code I have tried so far in R with example source:
res.aov <- anova_test(data = pra, dv = ProtC, wid = Plant, within = c(Age, Treatment))

https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/repeated-measures-anova-in-r/
With this, while I can get a summary of my data, it appears due to the unpaired nature of the data it will not run and I receive the following error:
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases

#Ancova

    model <- aov(Protein ~ Age * Treatment + Error(Vigor), data = pr)

https://rstudiodatalab.medium.com/how-to-perform-repeated-measures-ancova-in-r-a-complete-guide-25ef736bc672
With this, I can get values however I still see no statistical significance, which has me worried its still an incorrect test for the dataset.

What is your research hypothesis?  State it precisely and formulate the corresponding null and alternative hypotheses.  Until you do this, no one can tell you what analysis is appropriate for your data.

Sorry I didn't want to get too wordy.
H1: Under the treatment, protein values will significantly increase; younger and older leaves will differ in their response. An increase in in vigor index proportionally increases protein in the plant.

It's not a question of wordiness.  Every statistical analysis must be accompanied by a statement of the research hypothesis being tested.  It is a requirement, in as much as the computations themselves.  Otherwise, no one will know exactly what you are trying to do.  Every published paper with a statistical analysis in it states a research hypothesis.  The reader should not have to guess your objective by reading model statements written in programming code.  Are you trying to detect a treatment effect after controlling for other variables?  What are the assumptions you are making?

H0: No difference in protein occurs under the treatment; younger and older leaves show the same protein content. Vigor does not impact protein values.

It is a drought stress treatment. We are controlling for water, light, and temperature. It is a preliminary study into soluble proteins, so we are really just trying to learn more about our study organism.

So my suggestion is to look at a mixed effects model with repeated measures (MMRM), not ANCOVA, because you have fixed effects (treatment, leaf age) and random effects (vigor index).  Moreover, you may potentially have a correlation structure to take into account.  Also consider whether the model assumptions are applicable to your data before continuing, as I do not know whether your experiment satisfies those assumptions.

Thank you for the advice!

First, that's three hypotheses.  Second, please edit your question to include the hypotheses.
